# error: cannot resolve symbol 'edit_message' in MyFirstApp tutorial

Tags: java, android

this is the code in MyActivity.java  :

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

It says it cannot resolve the symbol 'edit_message' (see 6th line).
Answers to this problem were to add this string to strings.xml, but it is already there, and declared just fine:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_display_message">My Message</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
</resources>
```

The error message in Gradle Build is:
Error:(21, 57) error: cannot find symbol variable edit_message

Why can't it find this string?

I've been staring at this for quite a while and almost ashamed I can't solve it.. I mean, it's a tutorial for crying out loud. Any help would be apreciated very much!

Comment: please post your build file

Comment: You are declaring edit_message as string resource and referencing it as edit text.

Comment: `R.id.edit_message` -> you say you have an _ID_ with that name; `<string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>` -> you create a _String_ with that name. We notice, an ID is not a String.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is looking for a ´EditText´ element with name "edit_message" (not for a String with this name), so your layout xml file should contain `EditText` element with `id` `edit_message`

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Comment: That solved it, though in this code, at android_id it says: Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix...  When I run the app it shuts down when I click the send button.

Comment: @BertUenk Sorry, there must be a colon `:` instead of underscore. I corected the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access a resource so:

```
String s = context.getResources().getString(id);
```

and the id is: `R.id.edit_message`

context can be replaced by `this.` or `getBaseContext()`.

By to access an `EditText` it needs to be declared in the Layout' XML file (or declared at run time).